# any way to inspect the value of a node's unconnected output socket?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I know that you can inspect [the value of the output socket of a geometry node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/inspection.html) when hovering it.  That is nice.

[image]

But is there a way to inspect the value of the output socket of a node when it is not connected ?

I guess that unconnected sockets are not computed to spare memory.
But it makes debugging more difficult.
It would be awesome to have it computed somehow, eg. when pressing a key while hovering the socket.

Comment: i think you are totally right. It makes no sense to compute something which isn't used at all. Not just to spare memory, but even more important: to be more performant.

Comment: Well, you link to the manual where it is clearly stated, no need for speculation: "_Socket values are only logged from when the node tree was executed, so a node must be connected to the Group Output to have a value for inspection. Values are not logged during rendering, to improve performance._" So, no values if the socket is not connected. If you still want to inspect them, you should maybe connect them to a _Viewer_ node and inspect them in the _Spreadsheet_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann seems like a reasonable answer to the question :)

Comment: Idea suggested on right-click select [here](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/MJ81/).